# Creating and deploying new Google Actions via Command Line / API Calls?

Tags: voice-recognition, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

Is there a way to create a new Action (for Google Assistant/Home) without having to click through a web UI? (i.e. using REST calls or API calls via command line)

Amazon released the Alexa Skills Kit (ASK) CLI a short while ago which provides this sort of functionality for their service but I can't find anything similar on Google's side. (It doesn't help that Google's Action creation platform is called API.AI which kind of skews search results)

The closest solution I've found to this is the "gactions" CLI (https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/gactions-cli) but this seems to cater solely for updating Actions. Action creation is still limited to a manual process.

Comment: have you found api to create actions ?

Comment: No luck I'm afraid, though I stopped looking a while back